# High Charts - Split color of bar chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a High Chart chart similar to this bar chart: http://jsfiddle.net/s4zzpLzL/

How would I got about spliting the bar colors so that the color of the bar up until `500` is grey and the color of the bar after is the color you see on the screen? See image below.

[image]

Comment: You'd have to use a second series for each series, and stack them. Then you'd have to link each dummy series to its main series, and you'd have to adjust the formatters for data labels, tool tips, etc, to account for the dummy series.  What is the purpose? Perhaps there's a better method to accomplish the end-goal....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set gradient color for series, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pscwnzk7/1/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    series: [{
        color: {
            linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 500],
            stops: [
                [0, '#ff0ff0'],
                [0.5, '#ff0ff0'],
                [0.5, '#f0f00f']
            ]
        },
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
    }]
});
```

The only problem with that solution is that you can't specify (in values) where will be break - try to resize chart. So you would need to update series color gradient on each window resize etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **`zones`** in each serie like this:

```
zones: [{
        value: 500,
        color: '#A0A0A0'
}]
```

**`value`** is the up until value, and **`color`** is the color of that zone. Here's your edited [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/s4zzpLzL/1/)

**EDIT:**

You can also use **`plotBands`** but it's not exactly what you would want: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/s4zzpLzL/2/)

There is also a plugin which I don't think covers exactly what you are asking: [**Plugin**](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/33/Multicolor%20series)

Other than these I don't think there is another way unless you alter your data and use [**`stacked bar`**](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked) chart. You will have to change all of your data though and it will be tiresome.

Comment: That's pretty close and thanks for the response, but I need it to split the colors at the point, so before the `500` is the grey and after that value it uses whatever color scheme. Is that possible?

Comment: @RaeinHashemi Do you also know if it's possible to get separate labels for separate zones in the legend? Couldn't find support for this in the docs!

Comment: @prateekj_ahead I don't think so, but you can ask this question separately and someone may have the answer for you. Good luck

Comment: @RaeinHashemi Hey I read the code later and figured they only render one legend item per series. So it's not possible as of now. :D Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use concept of grouping, threshold and negativeColor to achieve this. Create 2 series with the same data and overlap them with **grouping: false** and a **negativeColor: 'transparent'**

**demo:** **https://jsfiddle.net/1dp8L1gw/**

```
plotOptions: {
    bar: {
        grouping: false,
        borderWidth: 0
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [45.9, 71.5, 106.4],
    color: 'red'
}, {
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [45.9, 71.5, 106.4],
    color: 'blue',
    threshold: 50,
    negativeColor: 'transparent'
}]
```