# Highcharts column range change color for negative numbers

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am having issue with **HighCharts**, more specifically with Column range graph. I would like to have **red** color for **negative** numbers and **blue** color for **positive** numbers.

The current code give the **red** color to the bars with **Only** **positive** values, and **blue** color to those where the interval contains a **negative** value:

```
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'columnrange',
            inverted: false

        },

        title: {
            text: 'Temperature variation by month'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Observed in Vik i Sogn, Norway'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature ( °C )'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            columnrange: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    grouping:true,
                    formatter: function () {
                    if(this.y == 0)
                        return "";
                    else
                        return this.y;
                    }
                }
            }

        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Temperatures',
            color: '#FF0000',
            displayNegative: true,
            negativeColor: '#0088FF'  ,
            data: [
                [0, 9.4],
                [-8.7, 6.5],
                [-3.5, 9.4],
                [-1.4, 19.9],
                [0.0, 22.6],
                [2.9, 29.5],
                [9.2, 30.7],
                [7.3, 26.5],
                [4.4, 18.0],
                [-3.1, 11.4],
                [-5.2, 10.4],
                [-13.5, 9.8]
            ]
        }]

    });

});
```

The Current graph looks like:
[image]

The result needed should be like:

[image]

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bff9kn3m/2/)

Comment: At this moment, Highcharts allows you to set a threshold and color points according to param. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/s3c82p6w/. In the case that negative part should be colored, you need to split each (negative / positive point) into to points. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xdg67kuo/

Comment: Take a look at this [column chart with split colors](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42570192/5817953). Color range for numbers below threshold

Answer (score 3):

After some researchs and based on the comment above from @Sebastian here is the conclusion:

You can modify your `Data` by adding the index to match the xAxis like `Data[[Index,from,to],[SecondIndex,from,to]` etc... and when it comes to the **negative** values you can set Data `Data[[IndexForNegative,from,to],[IndexForNegative,from,to]...` for the same value.

```
$(function() {

  $('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
      type: 'columnrange'
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Temperature variation by month'
    },

    subtitle: {
      text: 'Observed in Vik i Sogn, Norway'
    },

    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Temperature ( °C )'
      }
    },

    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: '°C'
    },

    plotOptions: {
      columnrange: {
        negativeColor: 'red',
        threshold: 0,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          formatter: function() {               
          }
        }
      }
    },

    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Temperatures',
      data: [
                [0,0,9.4],
                [1,-8.7,0],[1,0,6.5], //spliting all data that has negative values using the same index
                [2,-3.5,0],[1,0,9.4],
                [3,-1.4,0],[2,0,19.9],
                [4,0.0],[4,0,22.6],
                [5,2.9, 29.5],
                [6,9.2, 30.7],
                [7,7.3, 26.5],
                [8,4.4, 18.0],
                [9,-3.1,0],[9,0,11.4],
                [10,-5.2,0],[10,0,10.4],
                [11,-13.5,0],[11,0,9.8]
            ]
    }]    
  });    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0ns43y47/

Comment: Seems that is what I was looking for! So only have to  split negative and positive and set them same index :). Amazing, how I could not try that before. Thank you for sharing and your time! :D

Comment: You are welcome, if that solves your problem you can accept it as an answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers